# Renaming multiple files in a directory

Tags: linux

I have files like below in linux

fil12.css-

file34.test.css-

test123.one.css-

test123.css

test.css

I want to remove the '-' from the end of the file name .

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got from the web - The below command doing good

ls *css- | while read src; do tgt=$(echo "$src" | sed 's/css-/css/'); mv "$src" "$tgt"; done

Answer (score 1):

If you use `zsh`, you can do this:

```
zmv '(*)-' '$1'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in *.css-; do mv "$f" $( echo "$f" | sed s/-$// ); done
```

Comment: You should quote your variables ("$f") in case there are spaces - that will fail with a file named "a file.css-".